# awk piping results in 'cannot open file' error

Tags: bash, awk

Given a fail which contains `"txt_to_be_ext",sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text, "test")`, I have a script, which extracts `"txt_to_be_ext"` and appends it at the front of the line `"txt_to_be_ext","txt_to_be_ext",sometext("txt_to_be_ext", some_more_text, "test")`.

The script looks like this:

`awk '{match($0,/^.*\(("[^"]+"),*/,a);$0=a[1]","$0}1' %file% | tail -n +3`

I'm attempting to pipe it into `tail -n +3` to get rid of the first few lines, as they contain the filepath of the executed script, but when executing that script, I get: `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file '|' for reading ...`

What gives?

Comment: I'd have expected the error message to be `cannot open file '%file%' for reading` unless you actually do have a file named `%file%` in your directory. What does `ls %file%` do? Is your file actually named `file` or is  `file` a variable that contains the real file name or something else? You tagged your question with bash but to be sure - are you on UNIX or Windows? If UNIX and `file` is a variable, what happens when you replace `%file%` with `"$file"`?

Comment: `file` is a variable that contains the real file name. I'm calling the script using `script.bat file filename.txt`. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Then save the awk script in a file and execute it as `awk -f script file` to avoid WIndows nightmarish quoting rules which are what you're falling foul of right now. Or even better, install cygwin on top of Windows and run your UNIX tools from that.